Jolt transform nested objects into array
Given the following Json input how do I write a Jolt spec to transform the input into the desired output below. I am unsure how to deal with turning nested objects in arrays and excluding the field "AllOff" while using the '*" operator. I have experimented with different specs https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception however I cannot seem to get the desired transformation.
INPUT
{
  "data": {
    "properties": {
      "info": {
        "type": "object",
        "$comment": "Evaluation Information",
        "required": [
          "evalDate",
          "evalType",
          "evalWeather"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "evalDate": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "date"
          },
          "evalType": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "1st Party",
              "2nd Party",
              "3rd Party"
            ],
            "default": "2nd Party"
          },
          "evalWeather": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "evaluator": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "phone": {
            "type": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ]
          },
          "email": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "email"
              },
              {
                "type": "null"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "AllOf": []
    }
  }
}

DESIRED OUTPUT
{
  "FormModel": {
    "Categories": [
      {
        "Title": "info",
        "fields": [
          {
            "Title": "evalDate",
            "DataType": "string"
          },
          {
            "Title": "evalType",
            "DataType": "string"
          },
          {
            "Title": "evalWeather",
            "DataType": "string"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Title": "evaluator",
        "fields": [
          {
            "Title": "id",
            "DataType": "string"
          },
          {
            "Title": "name",
            "DataType": "string"
          },
          {
            "Title": "phone",
            "DataType": [
              "string"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Title": "email",
            "DataType": [
              "string",
              "null"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}


Seems that it's expected to loop for the leaf nodes type, and then will easily determine the respective Titles by using $ wildcards such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "properties": {
              "*": {
                "type": "&3.&1.Data&",
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "type": "&5.&3.Data&"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "$": "&1.Title",
        "*": {
          "$": "&2.fields[#2].Title",
          "*": "&2.fields[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "FormModel.Categories[#2].&"
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Great, thanks! How do I exclude certain properties from being transformed? For example if I want to exclude the properties ['AllOff', 'AnyOff']

Hi @Tamdim, no worries. Lately realised that I missed removing the nodes info, evaluator, and just fixed it. Btw, those properties already don't exist in the returning result, I mean I didn't understand your nw case..
